# Error trying to manage remote computers on a domain

Tags: active-directory, domain, remote-access

I am having trouble managing a computer that is within my domain.

Login to our DC, I right click the computer, and select Manage: 
After connecting to a domain joined computer(windows 7), on the Local Users and Groups I have a Red cross, with an error that I do not have access to it.

I suspect that the local user (whom have local admin rights - don't ask!  ) has done some configurations to it.

What are my options? if I do NOT have physical access to this computer?

- If I disable the computer from the domain - will that be good?
- any startup script?

My DC is W2K3 R2
His system is either W7 64bit

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that the user removed the default nesting of "DOMAIN\Domain Admins" into the local "Administrators" group. Since the user has "Administrator" rights on the PC they can do that.

You could use "Restricted Group" policy to "force" this nesting, but the user could always take a virtual "crowbar" to their machine's registry and break Group Policy processing (since they have Administrator rights). Odds are good they won't do this, but they could.

Disabling the Computer Object would prevent anyone from logging-on with a domain account on the PC while attached to the network. It would be trivial to disconnect the network cable, logon with cached credentials, and re-connect the network cable, though.

This sounds like a management problem and not a technical problem. Assuming the user actually has done this I would think that running this problem up the management chain (since the user is, in effect, "breaking" an IT resource) is probably your best course of action. Trying to "fix" it with a technical "arms race" is a lose / lose scenario for you and the company. The computer doesn't belong to the user and they shouldn't be treating it like it does.

Comment: My first thought as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is extremely old but this is actually a very simple fix.  RPC has many spokes to its wheel. One of them allows the Computer Management remote access but this is linked to the Remote Registry . Simply enable remote registry on your workstation in your domain.